# How can I view labels of shorter meeting blocks in "New Outlook" mode in a small window

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

Microsoft Outlook, when viewing a calendar in "New Outlook" mode, and when using a smaller window size, doesn't show labels for 15 minute blocks of time.  This is a problem if the goal is to view the day or week's meetings at a glance.

[image: New Outlook calendar view]

Making the window taller addresses the issue.  However, on my laptop monitor with my preferred OS zoom level I cannot make the window tall enough unless I extend the window beyond the height of the display.

The previous UI provided a zoom slider in the bottom right of the window, which scaled the calendar separately from the window size.  Using this, the calendar can be zoomed in enough to view these 15-minute meetings even in a smaller window.

[image: Calendar view prior to "New Outlook"]

I do not see any similar zoom option in "New Outlook" mode.

Is there a way to view the labels of 15 minute meetings in "New Outlook" mode with a smaller window size?

Comment: Where is this new outlook mode? In desktop version? Web? Android? iOS?

Comment: I'm using macOS version of Outlook.  Google tells me that Windows has the same thing.  [The new Outlook for Mac](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/the-new-outlook-for-mac-6283be54-e74d-434e-babb-b70cefc77439), [New Outlook for Windows](https://insider.office.com/en-us/blog/the-new-outlook-for-windows-helps-you-be-more-productive-and-in-control-of-your-inbox)

Answer (score 0):

No. There isn't a zoom option in "New Outlook" mode.
You can go to view-calendar settings to modify the time scale to 15 minutes.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe it's a Mac vs. PC thing, but I do not see such a "View" menu, or any way to adjust this particular aspect of the calendar.

Answer (score 0):

Could you find view all outlook setting in outlook for mac?
I can find it here.(It's windows.)
[image]

Update:
Sorry for that. According to my research, it seems modify the time scale is only available on outlook for windows.

But I found you can open the zoom follow the below screenshot in outlook for mac.
[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the "Zoom" menu option under "Window" in macOS is the standard one in all apps that maximizes the window.  So it changes the window size, which (as previously mentioned) doesn't actually fix the issue I'm seeing.

Comment: Ahh, I think there isn't a way to zoom the calendar. Because the new outlook is still in the process of updating, feed it back to Microsoft and wait them to fix it.

Comment: How's everything going now? Because the new outlook is still in process, i would suggest you to use the old outlook to instead of it.